# Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be an i.i.d. sequence with distribution function $F_X$.

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be  an  i.i.d.  sequence  with  distribution  function $F_X$. 
Define the samplestatistic $T=\frac{\#\{X_i\::\: X_i\: \in\: (-2,2)\}}{4n}$, where $\#A$ denotes the number of elements in the set $A$.

For large $n$, $T$ is with high probability approximately equal to? 
(Result is: $\frac{P(-2<X<2)}{4}$)

I have no clue how to solve it, can someone help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ equal $1$ if $X_i\in (-2,\,2)$ and $0$ otherwise, so $Y_i$ is Bernoulli-distributed, with $P(Y_i=1)=P(X_i\in (-2,\,2))$. Then $T_i$ is $1/4$ the mean of the $Y_i$, so the result follows from the central limit theorem.

Comment: Ohh, this makes sense! I got it! Thanks a lot :)